# Asymptotic equivalence allows difference by a constant factor?

Tags: asymptotics

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) and other sources define "asymptotically equivalent" as: two functions $f$ and $g$ are asymptotically equivalent if:

$$
\lim\limits_{x \to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1
$$

But we regard $n^2$ and $2n^2$ as asymptotically equivalent, and these always have a ratio of 2 between them.  Is there a different definition of "asymptotically equivalent" that I should be using?

[This MIT Problem Session](https://youtu.be/IPSaG9RRc-k?feature=shared&t=1190) from 2020 illustrates calling $n^3$ and $\binom{n}{3}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}$ asymptotically equivalent. If you back up a bit from the time where the link starts, you'll see (actually, hear) the algebra spelled out.

Comment: "we regard $n^2$ and $2n^2$ as asymptotically equivalent": where do you draw this from ? What is *your* definition of asymptotic equivalence ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well, I suppose I'm still looking for definitions, but I thought asymptotic behavior was commonly considered equivalent if both functions differ by no more than a constant factor. No?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Now I think I'm more confused. You said in [this comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/161817/asymptotic-equivalence-allows-difference-by-a-constant-factor?noredirect=1#comment338370_161818) that "to a constant factor" is never regarded as equivalent to "asymptotically equivalent". Could you post an answer that spells this out clearly? If it's just a matter of competing terminologies, it would be nice to see them spelled out; or if there is something more to it, like reasons or contexts where one is preferred, it would be nice to see that spelled out, too.

Comment: First give us a reference of the definition of *asymptotically equivalent* that you found and made you ask this question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Are you asking for a reference because that will help you write an answer, or as a pedagogical move to teach me to look up references? I am worried that this is a distraction from my question. I am asking on SE to get the benefit of other people's greater experience with the literature, the informal customs, and the subject matter itself.

Comment: I am asking because I believe that you will find no definition that matches your statement. [Presumably you will come up with some reference and either I will tell you why it is not relevant, or I will apologize.]

Comment: @YvesDaoust OK, I added a link to Wikipedia for the first definition (which cites a textbook by de Bruijn) and a link to an MIT Problem Session that illustrates the second definition "live". I hope your answer, though, addresses my question (about asymptotic equivalence in general, or the semantics of "asymptotically equivalent" in general), and is not limited to the specifics of these references.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple notions/definitions of asymptotic.  You need to pick one that is appropriate for your goals.

One approach to asymptotics is exactly as you have stated (see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis).  This notion cares about constant factors.  It is commonly used in mathematics.  Standard notation is $f(x) \sim g(x)$.

Another approach to asymptotics ignores constant factors.  This is standard in computer science.  In particular, we write $f(x) = \Theta(g(x))$ for two functions that behave the same asymptotically, in this sense.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation.

Which one to use depends on what you care about.  In computer science, we often care about analyzing the running time of algorithms, in a theoretical model where we ignore constant factors... hence we typically use the second notion.

I have only ever heard the phrase "asymptotically equivalent" used for the first kind of use of asymptotics, but I don't know whether that is an accepted terminology or just my personal experience.

Comment: I don't think that $f(x) = \Theta(g(x))$ are ever read as "$f$ and $g$ are asymptotically equivalent". They only are "to a constant factor". Also check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Generalizations_and_related_usages.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, good point.  I've edited my answer.  Thank you for the feedback.